# user.is_authenticated returns False with custom backend

Tags: django, authentication

I've created a custom backend for my application in order to let people log in with ldap. Seems like everything is working, apart from one thing:
I am checking if "user.is_authenticated" in template to show *"Log out"* button for authenticated users, and it seems to return false all the time.

I am using standard django LoginView. Before I added my custom backend it all worked just fine, and I only rewrote the **"authenticate()"** function the way it says in django docs.

How could I fix it?

My backend is:

```
class MyBackEnd(object):
"""
This is the custom backend to authenticate the user in the DB.
if this authentication fais then django default authentication  will get called
"""

def authenticate(self, request, username, password):

    #here comes server address and search templates

    try:
        return User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            l = ldap.initialize(server)
            l.protocol_version = 3
            l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

            l.simple_bind_s(username, password)

            r = l.search(base, scope, filter, attrs)
            type, user = l.result(r, 60)

            if len(user) == 1:

                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
                user.save()
                return user

        except:
            print("Failed to connect with ldap")
            return None


def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(username=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `get_user`:

```
return User.objects.get(username=user_id)
```

Is `username` stands for primary key in User model?
Try to replace following line by this:

```
return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped!